# Portaudio: how to make two devices play different signals simutaneously?

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I am trying to make a C program with portAudio that can play several **different** sounds simutaneously with **several** speakers attached to the **same** computer (a PC, but preferrably also on other OS).

I use `Pa_OpenStream` twice to open two streams on two different devices (e.g. `PaStream *stream1` for device "speaker 1" plays "audio 1"; `stream2` for "speaker 2" plays "audio 2"), and I can start each one of them, with expected output from each device. But when I try starting the two streams at the same time, with something like (in the same thread)

```
 Pa_StartStream(stream1);
 Pa_StartStream(stream2);
 Pa_StopStream(stream1);
 Pa_StopStream(stream2);
 ...
```

I hear sound from both devices, but the sound is terrible - something like noise.

**So, what is the proper way of playing two different sounds at the same time on two devices? How could I solve the problem?**

Comment: C programs are usually tagged with `c` and not with `c++` (which is a different language).

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post more of your code. You're just showing where you start/stop a stream playing. But, we need to see how the stream was setup: Which audio source/file and what output device, etc.